# How to access child element from parent using react testing library?

Tags: react-testing-library

i have dom like so

```
<label value="false" data-testid ="source" class="StyledSwitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="source" >
    <i class="ball-container"></i>
    <span class="label" data-enabled="On" data-disabled="Off"></span>
</label>
```

how can i access input element using label with data-tesid source

i have tried something like below,

```
const element = screen.getByTestId('source').firstChild();
```

but this gives error "object is possibly null" cannot invoke an object which is possibly null. how to fix this

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

const element = getByTestId('source').firstChild;

Comment: Do you mind going further in depth to explain the reasoning behind this answer?

Comment: I don't know why it's downvoted. It worked for me as the best answer here.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a querySelector to select the input, like this:

```
const element = screen.getByTestId('source').querySelector('input');

if(element) {
    /// Do something...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a querySelector:

```
const element = getByTestID('').firstchild;
```